# Best way to create a list from another list's members in Scala

Tags: list, scala

I'm trying to create an immutable list in Scala from another list. By that I mean that I have list a and I want to make list b which is every `a.myVariable`. What I'm looking for is a quick way to do this without using a mutable list.

For example:

```
a = (person1, person2, person3)
```

and I want a list

```
b = (person1.name,person2.name,person3.name)
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this in Scala?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `map` method available on collections. Here is an example:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String)
defined class Person

scala> val a = List(Person("test1"), Person("test2"), Person("test3"))
a: List[Person] = List(Person(test1), Person(test2), Person(test3))

scala> val b = a.map(_.name)
b: List[String] = List(test1, test2, test3)
```

You can find more info in the [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). `map` is higher-order function that takes another function as argument and produces new list by applying this function on each element of the list.

Answer (score 4):

This is identical to tenshi's answer, just a different notation.

```
val b = for (person <- a) yield person.name
```